# How to know what values are passed by Post request

Tags: php, html, request

I can know the values passed by `GET` requests as seen in the following image. But what about `POST` request? How can I determine values passed by `POST` request if **I'm not the coder of the page?**

[image]

Comment: Open Dev Tools on your browser and look at the Post event in the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using PHP, you can get the POST values via this variable: $_POST

More info on:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_post.asp

Comment: "I'm not the coder of the page?" Means they won't have access to the codebase

Comment: If you are not the coder, it is not possible to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Test (right click + inspect element, img1), then in the window that opens you will see a tab that says (network) there you can see all the calls that are made, you can also filter them by calls, js, css, img and xhr that I think It will be most useful for you.

If the call is not asynchronous, try to see it directly from the server:

```
var_dump($_POST, $_GET);
```

Comment: If you cannot, it is not possible to obtain the values, it is necessary to be able to modify the source code.

Comment: come on boy if it ain't use https protocol, there must be some ways.

Comment: If you just want to know what parameters are being submitted in a form, with javascript you can get that information
`document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("submit", handleForm);

function handleForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var elements = document.getElementById("test").elements;
    var obj ={};
    for(var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i++){
        var item = elements.item(i);
        obj[item.name] = item.value;
    }
console.log(obj);
}`
replace the id with that of your form and paste the code in the console